# jQuery fadeIn() called repeatedly not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a part of an JS-scanning function which runs about 3-5 times / sec.

Below is what I want to obtain .. but it (obviosly) does not work ... because it keeps "resetting" the fadeIn function 3-5 times every second.

```
if (scanResult) {
     dosomething();
} else {
     // Show error message
     $("#error").fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
}
```

I could call a seperate function and/or checks with timestamps when it last was called.

But ... there must be a smarter jQuery-way?

Comment: Maybe you need a new "error" panel each time, so the old/only one is not reused each time.  You might like to consider a 3rd-party "toast notification" plugin such as [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty.

```
if (scanResult) {
     dosomething();
} else {
     // Show error message
     if(!$("#error").hasClass("shown"))
         $("#error").addClass("shown").fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(() => {removeClass("shown");});
}
```

Comment: Probably want that `.removeClass("shown")` inside the `.fadeOut(complete)` callback otherwise it's removed immediately.   `removeClass` is not affect by `.delay()` so you essentially have `.addClass("shown").removeClass("shown").fadeIn()...`

Comment: Thx for the hint

Comment: Actually ... it seems to only run once. But by inserting a minor delay - it keeps "popping" up with 2 sec intervals:


$("#error").addClass("shown").fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut().delay(2000).removeClass("shown");